# Abstract class that requires abstract property

Tags: typescript

I am working with these dual abstract classes, and I am trying to require the second abstract class to have a property that is another abstract class. But it's failing.

```
abstract class Static<C extends {[key: string]: any}> {
    abstract doughnut: boolean
}

class AlphaStatic extends Static<{ love: true }> {
    doughnut = true
}

abstract class Dynamic<C extends {[key: string]: any}> {
    abstract static: Static<C>
}

class AlphaDynamic extends Dynamic<{ love: true }> {
    static = AlphaStatic
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgyhYECWsAPAMIICmAHhGQHYAmGA3gNoDWZAngFwKRR40A5gF0ewGhwC%20APgSMAUAiUJQfOIjoB7AK6CAFjW0QeITZuRlx8yfPko0GAILIADnuDZcBclVoMsOPhEjAjImgBuZDzQ2mQIMnKKylq6BkYIALwIMWTWtqrQ6kio6AgAIhw0wAC2BCQ%201PRMbJw8fAIiYhIJCsoq4IXwvIEEPJ5BJNJ5diVOru4VVbWwDX4YizV1IWGR0VCx8bK9ypBeK1nObh4jsNZAA)

How can I fix this?

> Property 'static' in type 'AlphaDynamic' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Dynamic<{ love: true; }>'.
> Property 'doughnut' is missing in type 'typeof AlphaStatic' but required in type 'Static<{ love: true; }>'.ts(2416)
> Untitled-2(2, 14): 'doughnut' is declared here.

Comment: Did you mean `static: AlphaStatic`? As of right now, you're assigning `static` the *value* `AlphaStatic`, not an instance thereof.

Comment: yes I think I want new AlphaStatic()

Comment: If you want the property's value to actually be a class, not an instance, then the type should be `new (...args: any[]) => Static<C>`.

Comment: @kaya3 perfect good to know might want that instead

Comment: Also, `static` is a keyword in TS. Avoid using it as an identifier.

Comment: `abstract doughnut: boolean` -- what would be the meaning of an abstract data attribute?

Answer (score 3):

Was missing "new"

```
abstract class Static<C extends {[key: string]: any}> {
    abstract doughnut: boolean
}

class AlphaStatic extends Static<{ love: true }> {
    doughnut = true
}

abstract class Dynamic<C extends {[key: string]: any}> {
    abstract static: Static<C>
}

class AlphaDynamic extends Dynamic<{ love: true }> {
    static = new AlphaStatic()
}
```